# why a file has x permission for others but i can't run it with another user

Tags: permissions, services

I have installed splunk service on `/opt`.

```
-r-xr-xr-x 1 splunk splunk 477488 May 19  2017 /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk
```

If I want to see the service status or restart it I should use these commands:

```
/opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk stop 
/opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk status
/opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk start
```

When I run these commands with *root* or *splunk* they work properly but when I use these commands with another user it says:

```
bash: /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk: Permission denied
```

It has the x permission for others. What is the reason that I get this error? How I can fix it not giving `sudo` permission to that user?

Comment: services are generally controlled via systemctl, not via their binary directly. I'd rather give that user sudo rights on that particular service, than full control over the binary. See this for pointers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/72267/how-to-allow-execution-without-prompting-for-password-using-sudo This way you can also control if that user can only start/stop or restart the service.

Comment: Does each directory down from the root directory to `/opt/splunkforwander/bin` also have the `x` bit set for the relevant user?

Comment: @BadSnowflake, maybe yeah, though the service then needs to have systemd unit file, and we don't know if that one does. As for sudo, if the service runs under an ordinary user's UID, does it matter if they have access to the binary? They could run any program under their own UID anyway.

Comment: @Kusalananda the `splunkforwarder` didn't have the permission. i added x for others. now i get new error `Pid file "/opt/splunkforwarder/var/run/splunk/splunkd.pid" unreadable.: Permission denied` now i think  i should ask is it safe to add r permission for other about a pid file